# Is there a way of saying "if anything == anything"? (Python)

Tags: python, random, while-loop

sample code:

```
import random

x = random.randint(1, 101)
y = random.randint(1, 101)
z = random.randint(1, 101)

print(x, y, z)
```

Now, is there an easier way of saying

```
while x == y or x == z or y == z:
    x = random.randint(1, 101)
    y = random.randint(1, 101)
    z = random.randint(1, 101)
```

Because the more variables you have, the longer that while statement goes and the uglier and more frustrating it gets if you forget something.

Something like: If any variable is equal to any other one: reroll.

Thanks!

Comment: `while len({x,y,z}) < 3`

Comment: If you start using many variables holding random values, you should consider a list (and you can then use `if len(set(myvars)) < len(myvars):`. But in that case, you should consider using NumPy's random module and functions therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have three variables you can check if any are equal to another using

```
len({x,y,z}) < 3
```

If you have an arbitrary number of variables in a list `values`, you can check if any value is repeated using:

```
len(set(values)) < len(values)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you *actually* need in this particular case, is [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
x, y, z = random.sample(range(1, 101), 3)
```

That way you will always get unique values without having to re-roll.

Comment: Thank you! Even though that wasn't really my question I will use it in my code, because it's making things lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `set` to get unique values and check whether length of set is smaller than count of input elements.

E.g.

```
while len({x, y, z}) < 3:
    x = ...
    y = ...
    z = ...
```